# internet connection inside a fragment android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to check for internet connection, here's my code... all internet permissions have been added inside the manifest.

```
    boolean connected = false;                           
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            connected = true;
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            connected = true;
        } else {
            connected = false;
        }

    }
    return connected;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you showed what you tried, but forgot to mention a problem. So what's a problem?

Comment: Clarify your problem You have just paste code and explaining where is problem.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention the problem..... When i call the method to check connection inside an Activity that extends a Fragment the application stops.

Answer (score 0):

please try this :

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected() && netInfo.isAvailable())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```